# Discriminating periodic signals from aperiodic ones

Tags: time-series, descriptive-statistics

I was wondering if there are any well-established or **known low-dimensional [descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_%28pattern_recognition%29)** (i.e. **heuristics or features**) for the problem of discriminating periodic 1D signals from aperiodic ones.

**My take so far:**

- I'm thinking there may be ways of compactly encoding the DFT spectrum of the signal if I assume that I can first detect the `K` most dominant frequencies in the signal.
- Similarly, I'm wondering if there are any low-dimensional statistical descriptors of a signal's autocorrelation that somehow preserve information about it's periodicity.

Comment: Maybe you need to clarify what you're looking for. Consider the two following facts. **(1)** If we're considering uniformly sampled discrete signals of finite length, then the complex exponentials span the space of all such real-values functions. So, *every* such signal has some (unique) periodic representation. **(2)** In terms of compactness of encoding, consider a square wave, which needs an infinite number of coefficients to be fully represented (and then only in the $L_2$ sense). Here there is an obvious pattern to the values of the coefficients, but that need not be the case in general.

Comment: Thanks @cardinal. I'm not sure I follow, but the descriptor I am looking for can be lossy. I'm not looking for a lossless encoding of the periodic signal, but for a compact descriptor that can help me discriminate periodic vs non-periodic signals. As for the type of periodicity, I mean "observable periodicity" within the window that holds the discrete samples. Not sure if this addresses your question, but I am happy to clarify these points in the OP.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. The point of item (1) is to indicate that "discriminating" between periodic and nonperiodic (sampled) signals is not generally meaningful without placing further constraints on the problem. The point of item (2) is to show that even when there is a signal of fixed period, it may take an infinite number of harmonics to represent it, and so a "compact" description using the spectrum may not be possible.

Comment: If I am interpreting your comment correctly, by "observable periodicity" you mean that if $n$ is the number of points in your sample, then the period $T$ of a periodic signal satisfies $T \ll n$. Yes?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by "observable periodicity" - with a minor note: I'm not looking for exact periodicity and need tolerance for noise. As for the actual classification, I can afford to (and from your comment, I understand that I necessarily will) lose information in the descriptor. What I am looking for is a descriptor that "does well" statistically in separating these two classes, when I feed it to, say, a linear classifier. Note that the performance will depend on the actual classifier. As with any features, I just want to make the classification easier in first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is actually a difficult research question. As mentioned by @cardinal, the FT suffers from major drawbacks.

If I recall, the distribution of the square module of the coefficients is a *scaled* $\chi^2$ with 1 degree of freedom. This might be used to test that your signal is a white noise, but rejection will not tell you that it is periodic.

[Wavelets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet) turn out to be an incredibly powerful tool to study noisy pseudo-periodic (and long memory) signals. Unfortunately they are not usually used to detect periodicity and I am not aware of simple descriptors of periodicity. I came across [that paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.math.umd.edu%2F~jjb%2FPeriDet.ps&ei=-0HLT--jNY200QX7iZm4AQ&usg=AFQjCNGT2I4Cg6FX8LF2P8fVTT24y2KEvQ&sig2=vDVlgzjLMpoeTg13ARi1Kw) which addresses just that question, but if you are not familiar with the wavelet theory it might be hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is best to detect periodicity in the frequency domain.  However, if for example there is a twelve month period and the time step is one month then at lag 12 and multiples of it you should see high correlations.  If there is no periodic components there would be no peaks at a particular lag and its multiples.  So maybe as a partial answer to your question this could possibly work.  But I don't think there is any very definitive approach.